# Uploading APK in Google PlayStore

Tags: android, upload, apk, release, google-play

Is it possible to upload an APK of an App to the PlayStore, but can I set it up so that before it will be released in the "production-phase", it first has to be approved?

I tried uploading it as a draft, but then I only see the options to "move" it to alpha- or beta-test, but not to production.

In other words: I would like to upload it to the PlayStore, but actually release it later without uploading the APK again?

Comment: yes it is its called beta release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your query:

> in other words: I would like to upload it to the PlayStore, but actually release it later without uploading the APK again?

you need to select beta-test for to upload it to the PlayStore, but actually release it later without uploading the APK again.